# AWS Glue: How to add a column with the source filename in the output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

Does anyone know of a way to add the source filename as a column in a Glue job?

We created a flow where we crawled some files in S3 to create a schema. We then wrote a job that transforms the files to a new format, and the writes those files back to another S3 bucket as CSV, to be used by the rest of our pipeline. What we would like to do is get access to some sort of job meta properties so we can add a new column to the output file that contains the original filename.

I looked through the AWS documentation and the aws-glue-libs source, but didn't see anything that jumped out. Ideally there would be some way to get metadata from the `awsglue.job` package (we're using the python flavor).

I'm still learning Glue, so apologies if I'm using the wrong terminology. I tagged this with the spark tag as well, because I believe that's what Glue is using under the covers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with spark in your etl job:

```
var df = glueContext.getCatalogSource(
  database = database,
  tableName = table,
  transformationContext = s"source-$database.$table"
).getDynamicFrame()
 .toDF()
 .withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name())

glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(
  connectionType = "s3",
  options = JsonOptions(Map(
    "path" -> args("DST_S3_PATH")
  )),
  transformationContext = "",
  format = "parquet"
).writeDynamicFrame(DynamicFrame(df, glueContext))
```

Remember it works with getCatalogSource() API only and not with create_dynamic_frame_from_options()

Comment: Works great! I imported `input_file_name` with `from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name`.

Comment: is this still expected to work in 2022 with `glueContext.create_sample_dynamic_frame_from_catalog` ?

when reading from S3 files, the filename can be added. but when reading from a catalog create by a glue crawler it cannot. 

i am now looking into using athena to write a new table with a query to get it to work https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/find-s3-source-file-athena-table-row/

Answer (score 5):

With an AWS Glue Python auto-generated script, I've added the following lines:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

## Add the input file name column
datasource1 = datasource0.toDF().withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name())

## Convert DataFrame back to DynamicFrame
datasource2 = datasource0.fromDF(datasource1, glueContext, "datasource2")
```

Then, in the `ApplyMapping` or `datasink` portions of the code,  you reference `datasource2`.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I am using an AWS Glue Python auto-generated script. I tried using the solution from [JcMaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23002/jcmaco) as this is exactly what I needed and it is a very simple solution to use `input_file_name()`.

However, I could not get that to work, my column always came back empty aside from the header of the column, but I *was* able to get the name of the Glue job and use that as a constant in a new column and it serves the same purpose as `input_file_name()` in this particular use case for me.

If you look at the top left of your script, you will see where the `args` variable gets created. Use `args` to get access to JOB_NAME as shown below.

How I did it:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

job_name = args['JOB_NAME'] # define new variable
```

(The JOB_NAME is passed in as a command line argument.)

Then, after the `datasource0` definition in your script, use `job_name` along with the `lit` function:

```
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = […] , transformation_ctx = "applymapping1") 
applymapping2 = applymapping1.toDF().withColumn("job_name", lit(job_name))
applymapping3 = applymapping1.fromDF(applymapping2, glueContext, "applymapping3")
```

In the example above, you would change the assignment of your `frame` parameter in your `datasink` definition to `applymapping3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Map transformation to apply a function to all records of a DynamicFrame](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html), inside the function you can add fields, one field can be the name of the job, that value can be [send as an argument to the AWS Glue Job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html#aws-glue-programming-python-calling-parameters):

```py
# add argument to the job
client.start_job_run(
               JobName = 'my_test_Job',
               Arguments = {
                 '--job_name':   'name', } )
```

```py
# read the argument
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                          ['job_name'])
arg_job_name = args["job_name"]

inputDyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    ...
)


def mapping(record: Dict[str, Any]):
    record["Job"] = arg_job_name
    return record 

mapped_dyF = Map.apply(frame=inputDyf, f=mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GlueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options` you can use the `attachFilename` key in `format_options` to add a column with the source filename [aws-glue-programming-etl-format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html)

```
dynamicFrame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://s3path"]},
    format="json",
    format_options={
        "multiline": True,
        "attachFilename": "your_filename_column_name"
    }
)
```