# Why is input_file_name() empty for S3 catalog sources in pyspark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to get the input file name (or path) for every file loaded through an S3 data catalog in AWS Glue.

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277563/aws-glue-how-to-add-a-column-with-the-source-filename-in-the-output) in a few places that `input_file_name()` should provide this information (though caveated that this only works when calling `from_catalog` and not `from_options`, which I believe I am!).

So the code below seems like it should work, but always returns empty values for every `input_file_name`.

```py
import sys

from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'TempDir'])
sc = SparkContext()
gc = GlueContext(sc)
spark = gc.spark_session


job = Job(gc)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


# Get the source frame from the Glue Catalog, which describes files in S3
fm_source = gc.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database='database_name',
    table_name='table_name',
    transformation_ctx='fm_source',
)

df_source = fm_source.toDF().withColumn('input_file_name', input_file_name())
df_source.show(5)
```

Resulting output:

```
+-------------+---------------+
|other_columns|input_file_name|
+-------------+---------------+
|           13|               |
|           33|               |
|           53|               |
|           73|               |
|           93|               |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Is there another way that I should be creating the frame that ensures `input_file_name()` is populated? I've now tried to build a source frame  through `create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog`, `create_dynamic_frame.from_options` and `getSource().getFrame()`, but I get the same result of an empty `input_file_name` column for each.

Comment: It might happen due to enabled `groupFiles` option (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/grouping-input-files.html). However, I'm not sure if it's possible to disable it for reading from a catalog

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk thanks! If I am reading the docs correctly, it seems like it should be automatically disabled for fewer than 50,000 files (my test bucket has ~100). I can't see the syntax to disable the option, even without reading from a catalog, though. Does this also mean that if my catalog includes (automatic) partitions, single file operation calls like `input_file_name()` will never work?

Comment: For anyone else looking, the relevant `groupFiles` setting is `none` when you wish to explicitly disable this functionality for inputs greater than 50,000 files

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to disable this option if reading directly from catalog. I used it when I loaded data directly from s3 using `create_dynamic_frame_from_options(...)` function

Comment: Have you tried reading the data into data frame and  then convert it to a dynamic frame?

Comment: @WillCroft have you found a solution ? thanks!!

Comment: @zhifff apologies for the slow reply, but yes we found a "solution" albeit with major caveats. See my answer below!

Comment: @WillCroft THANK YOU！！

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this to be impossible when using the [`groupFiles`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/grouping-input-files.html) option, given that behind the scenes Glue is concatenating files to create the optimal number of inputs. Thus, the concept of `input_file_name` does not make sense in this context, given the original file path is no longer a direct input.

However, the docs are slightly misleading in the sense that even for inputs fewer than 50,000 files, not explicitly disabling the option will trigger Glue to concatenate inputs depending on their file size. In our case, we have thousands of tiny input files (<1 MB) causing this behaviour.

You can easily verify this, by explicitly disabling the grouping (note this will have a severe performance impact for scenarios similar to ours:

```py
ds_s3 = self.gc.getSource(
    connection_type='s3',
    paths=paths,
    groupFiles='none',
)
fm_s3 = ds_s3.getFrame()
```

Of course, it is better not to have to depend on the input state or context, and so we ended up writing an AWS Lambda triggered on S3 `PUT` which writes metadata (including the filename and path) into the file itself.

Answer (score 13):

I also add my experience, in my case I received an empty result because calling the `cache()` method.

For example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.read.json("/my/folder/test.json")
df.cache()
df = df.withColumn("input_file_name", F.input_file_name())

df.show()
```

I receive

```
+-------------+---------------+
|other_columns|input_file_name|
+-------------+---------------+
|           13|               |
|           33|               |
|           53|               |
|           73|               |
|           93|               |
+-------------+---------------+
```

But if I remove the line `df.cache()` the column `input_file_name` shows correctly the input filenames.

A workaround might be calling `F.input_file_name()` before caching.

Comment: Brilliant insight!

Comment: This alo worked for me. Consider using `spark.catalog.clearCache()` if you need to drop the cached table in an interactive spark session (i.e. Jupyter notebook)

Comment: Yes!! That was the issue, but why? should I then cache later?

Comment: After `df.cache()`, I cannot get anything from `input_file_name`. If I run `df.unpersist()`, it starts to work.

Comment: Once you cache the data into spark nodes, they are no more seen as the original general formatted files from the spark's perspective. When you unpersist, the execution plan starts from the first point again, that is reading from raw input files.

Answer (score 4):

I found another weird behavior. When I add a `limit()` before `input_file_path` id does not work either.

This code has empty filename

```
df_raw = (spark
          .read
          .option("delimiter", ";")
          .csv(filepath,header = "true",inferSchema=True)      
          .select("COL1","COL2")
          .limit(1000)
          )

df_transform = (df_raw
          .withColumn("filename", f.input_file_name())
          )
```

This code works

```
df_raw = (spark
          .read
          .option("delimiter", ";")
          .csv(filepath,header = "true",inferSchema=True)      
          .select("COL1","COL2")
          )

df_transform = (df_raw
          .withColumn("filename", f.input_file_name())
          .limit(1000)
          )
```

Tooked me some time to figure that out, because I tried to speed up debuging with reading only a few rows.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is important since some people might be using this feature on production. We did some investigation within the Data Team of [MediaQX](https://www.mediaqx.com), and here are our findings. Kudos to [@Leyla Helin Çetin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12372328/leyla-helin-%C3%87etin) and [@Eren Sakarya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21764563/eren-sakarya).

Before the findings make sure that you are not using this `input_file_name` feature on Glue since it breaks when the file sizes are small. Make sure you add the necessary columns to your files, and do not depend on the path. If you are using pure spark you might not need to worry about this.

We checked all the responses to related posts, I will link them for a circular reading for the upcoming issue holders:

In this context, this is the most plausible solution, but in the glue context, it is not clear that it works perfectly or not and you might miss some glue features like bookmarks:
[How to append a new column with source name in the AWS Glue job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515833/how-to-append-a-new-column-with-source-name-in-the-aws-glue-job/57580525#57580525)

There are several approaches showing a mapping function approach but they all use `input_file_name` function she they are not accurate for a production solution
[Using S3 folder structure as meta data in AWS Glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71739384/using-s3-folder-structure-as-meta-data-in-aws-glue/71783064#71783064)

Some people solved their issues by using job name but it is not plausible for different configurations:
[AWS Glue: How to add a column with the source filename in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277563/aws-glue-how-to-add-a-column-with-the-source-filename-in-the-output)

And in this thread, `groupFiles` option is discussed, in the AWS documentation it states that it is not working with parquet files but it works actually, and it is not a direct solution for this issues.

Another solution is to remove the dots from file names but it is not a solution in our case:
[Glue dynamic frame is not populating from s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75815120/glue-dynamic-frame-is-not-populating-from-s3-bucket)

You can make the function work by setting this parameter: `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", "1MB")`

However, we think that it increases the reading time and it makes the `input_file_name` function to work properly. We think that the function is halted when the reading process is very fast. And please note that, the total size of the read files should be larger than the parameter you set, so it is not a perfect solution either. In addition to that, it will slow down the jobs since the default value is 128MB for this parameter.

I hope this answer helps, please shout out your findings so may be the AWS staff might use the answer while fixing this bug.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, there are a few edge cases wherein this method, 'input_file_name()', does not work as expected with DynamicFrame. In such cases, you can try using 'attachFilename' option with DynamicFrame  to retrieve file path for the records.

Here is an example:

==
Code:

```
dyf6_ = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://awsglue-datasets/examples/highly-partitioned-table/year=2021/month=12/"],
        "recurse":True,
        "groupFiles": "inPartition",
        "groupSize": "1048576"
    },
    format="json",
    format_options={
        "attachFilename": "filenameCol"
    }
)
dyf6_.toDF().show()
```

Comment: Where is this `attachFilename` option documented?

Comment: This is what I wanted exactly. works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issues as Vzzarr. When I created the `input_file_path` column after calling `cache` on the dataframe, the file path was empty. But When I created the `input_file_path` before calling `cache`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If all the above still couldn't work, add this..

```
spark.catalog.clearCache()
```

to clear all cache in the cluster.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me because I had a deprecated runtime of my databricks cluster (7.6) and I tried it on 7.3 LTS which worked. :)