# How to append a new column with source name in the AWS Glue job?

Tags: pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I have searched on stack overflow to find out how to append a new column with source file names as values.
But, it didn't work out as expected.

In my final parquet file, I found a new column named input_file_name, but the value is empty. (like "")

I am wondering which step I neglected.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "mydb", table_name = "mytable", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

datasource1 = datasource0.toDF().withColumn("input_file_name", F.input_file_name())

datasource2 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(datasource1, glueContext, "datasource2")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource2, mappings = [("input_file_name", "string", "input_file_name", "string"), 
("Profile", "struct", "Profile","struct")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://temp/testing"}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Comment: I wonder if it would work if you used `from_options` when creating your dataframe.

Comment: How many files you have in your input and what format you are working with.Can you try setting groupFiles to none as shown below and let me know if it populated input_file_name with values? dynamicframe0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = mydb, table_name = mytable, additional_options={"groupFiles": "none"} )

Comment: Have you tried to convert the Glue DynamicFrame to Spark DataFrame? I had used the `input_file_name()` before with Spark DataFrames and it works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76130402/10389449 check out my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You cant use input_file_name() by converting dynamic frame to dataframe

You must use spark.read api to read data to dataframe. Next immediate step must be to use input_file_name() - before performing any operation on dataframe.

Remember aws glue has known issue that it works with upto 45gb data then it throws error. Increasing dpus won't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76130402/10389449 let me know your thoughts on my answer.